# No result with barcode scanner

Tags: android, android-camera, barcode-scanner

i'm new to Android apps. I'm trying to create a barcode scanner, but the result does not appear in my `edittext`.

Also, in the `onActivityResult` the following error is shown:

> The method onActivityResult(int, int, Intent) from the type new
>   View.OnClickListener(){} is never used locally

I have the class `intentIntegrator` and `IntentResult` in my project.

This a part of my code:

```
BtnBar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {           
   @Override
   public void onClick(View v) {            
      Intent intent = new Intent("com.google.zxing.client.android.SCAN");
      startActivityForResult(intent, 0);                            
   }               
   public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {;        
     if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK && requestCode == 0) {
        Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
        String result = extras.getString("SCAN_RESULT");            
        EditText desc = (EditText) findViewById(R.produto.desc);
        desc.setText(result);         
     }
     desc.setText(resultCode);
  }     
  //public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {
  }
 );
```

This is the XML code for the button:

```
    <EditText 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+produto/desc"
    android:enabled="false"
    />
<requestFocus />
```

Comment: Have you checked that your String `result` has the expected value?  Maybe that's just empty for some reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to move the `onActivityResult` method out into the activity rather than inside the `setOnClickListener`.

The hint that you are getting from the ide (eclipse I presume) is telling you that `onActivityResult` is never being used by your code base, this is because it is not in the correct place to be picked up by the activity when the:

```
Intent intent = new Intent("com.google.zxing.client.android.SCAN");
startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
```

code path returns.

Comment: Exactly right. This might also have been clearer if the OP had used `IntentIntegrator` since it would have demanded a reference to an `Activity`.